# Karma + Typescript -> es6

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, karma-runner

Trying to setup karma to unit test my ES6 transpiled code.  The full tool chain is:  Typescript -> ES6 -> Babel -> browserify.

Outside of Karma I have this chain working fine (using Gulp).

With my Karma setup I'm getting errors on the Typescript step:

> error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'IterableIterator'.
>   12 03 2016 16:52:09.323:ERROR [preprocessor.typescript]: error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Iterator'.
>
> error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Iterator'.
>   12 03 2016 16:52:09.323:ERROR [preprocessor.typescript]: error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Symbol'.`

Here's my karma.conf

```
module.exports = function(config) {
 config.set({

// base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
frameworks: ['browserify','jasmine'],

preprocessors: {
    'src/**/test.ts' : ['typescript', 'babel', 'browserify'],
    'tests/**/tests.spec.js' : ['babel', 'browserify']
 },

typescriptPreprocessor: {
  options: {
    target: 'es6'
    }
 },

babelPreprocessor: {
  options: {
    presets: ['es2015'],
    sourceMap: 'inline'
  }
}, 

browserify: {
   debug:true
},

files: [
   'src/**/test.ts',
   'tests/**/*.js'
 ],

// list of files to exclude
exclude: [

],


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


plugins: [
'karma-typescript-preprocessor',
'karma-babel-Preprocessor',    
'karma-browserify',
'karma-jasmine',
'karma-firefox-launcher',
'karma-chrome-launcher'
],

// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: false,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR ||     config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,

browsers: ['Chrome'],

// If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
captureTimeout: 60000,


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
singleRun: false
 });
};
```

And here's my test.ts file:

```
"use strict"
function thisIsAtest(myParam:string) {
  const pi = 3.14;

 }
```

New to Typescript and my google powers are failing me ):

**Update:**   So the above configuration makes use of the babel and typescript karma *preprocessors*.   I am still unable to get that toolchain to work.   But I was able accomplish my end goal by having karma-browserify handle the transformations directly.   So my browserify section now looks like this:

```
browserify: {
    debug: true,
    plugin: ['tsify'],
    transform: [['babelify', {presets:["es2015"], extensions:[".ts",".js"]    }]]
    },
```

Notice the double brackets within the transform section -- forgetting those tripped me up when I initially started down this path.